# Applying an iterative/non-aggregating function to multiple subsets of data in R

Tags: r, function, dplyr, data.table

I am trying to run a function that requires indexing within subsets of a dataset, and I'm running into trouble with how to set up the function. Specifically, I'm trying to calculate the distance along a specific transect in a given year, so for each subset I need to 1) identify an endpoint in the transect, and 2) calculate the Euclidean distance along the line from that endpoint at all other locations within the subset.

The function appears to work if I treat the entire dataset as a single transect:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Transect = c(rep(1,4),rep(2,4)),
  YYYY = c(2015,2015,2016,2016,2015,2015,2016,2016),
  X = seq(2,16, by = 2),
  Y = c(1,2,3,5,6,13,22,31))

df$dist <- NA

f <- function(X, Y) {
  xs_start <- match(min(X), X)  #assumes no transects are perfectly N-S
  for (n in 1:length(X)){
    dist[n] <- (((Y[n]-Y[xs_start])^2)+((X[n]-X[xs_start])^2))^.5
  }
  return(dist)
}
attach(df)
f(X, Y)
detach(df)
```

However, running it on a subset of the data has been giving me trouble. I can subset the dataframe successfully using both `data.table` and `dplyr`, but I run into different problems when trying to run the functions on subsets. Most documentation I've found has focused on ways to aggregate subsets of data (and sometimes to then join the summary number back to the whole group).

Using `data.table`, I can get the first transect to calculate correctly, but the rest produce NAs and the entire resulting vector is then joined to each group rather than only the results from that subset.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[,f(X, Y), by = .(Transect, YYYY)]
```

Using `dplyr` is also an option, but again,  I'm not sure how to make it work for functions that don't aggregate data.

```
library(dplyr)
df  %>%
  group_by(Transect, YYYY) %>%
  mutate(dist = f(X, Y))
```

The above code results in `Error: Column 'dist' must be length 2 (the group size) or one, not 8`.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your function is giving errors even without grouped data

Comment: @akrun Even after restarting my R session and clearing out the environment, the function produces a vector for me when I copy and paste the first chunk of code--what errors are you getting?

Comment: I get `with(df, f(X, Y))
Error in dist[n] <- (((Y[n] - Y[xs_start])^2) + ((X[n] - X[xs_start])^2))^0.5 : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`  I don't `attach` as it can create issues

Comment: @akrun I was using attach to try to replicate the syntax of what was going to happen within dplyr/data.table, so I didn't want to use "df$"--and now that I'm going back through the code that seems to have carried through to when I was subsetting as well. If I change the function to refer to the entire dataframe and index everything using df$X, etc, it runs. That also seems like it would complicate the working within-subset part...

Comment: f <- function(df) {
  xs_start <- match(min(df$X), df$X)
  for (n in 1:length(df$X)){
    df$dist[n] <- (((df$Y[n]-df$Y[xs_start])^2)+((df$X[n]-df$X[xs_start])^2))^.5
  }
  return(df$dist)
}

f(df)

Answer (score 2):

To add a column `dist` that calculates Euclidean distances from an endpoint location (smallest X-coordinate) to all other locations in each transect-year group, you could do:

```r
## data
df <- data.frame(
    Transect = c(rep(1,4),rep(2,4)),
    YYYY = c(2015,2015,2016,2016,2015,2015,2016,2016),
    X = seq(2,16, by = 2),
    Y = c(1,2,3,5,6,13,22,31))

## with dplyr
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    group_by(Transect, YYYY) %>%
    mutate(dist = sqrt((Y - Y[which.min(X)])^2 + (X - min(X))^2)) %>%
    ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 8 x 5
#>   Transect  YYYY     X     Y  dist
#>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1        1  2015     2     1  0   
#> 2        1  2015     4     2  2.24
#> 3        1  2016     6     3  0   
#> 4        1  2016     8     5  2.83
#> 5        2  2015    10     6  0   
#> 6        2  2015    12    13  7.28
#> 7        2  2016    14    22  0   
#> 8        2  2016    16    31  9.22

## with data.table
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, dist := sqrt((Y - Y[which.min(X)])^2 + (X - min(X))^2), by = c("Transect", "YYYY")][]
#>    Transect YYYY  X  Y     dist
#> 1:        1 2015  2  1 0.000000
#> 2:        1 2015  4  2 2.236068
#> 3:        1 2016  6  3 0.000000
#> 4:        1 2016  8  5 2.828427
#> 5:        2 2015 10  6 0.000000
#> 6:        2 2015 12 13 7.280110
#> 7:        2 2016 14 22 0.000000
#> 8:        2 2016 16 31 9.219544
```